# Toggle Aspect Ratio

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I wrote this sub to toggle a shape's Lock Aspect Ratio.  It turns locks it but it doesn't unlock it

```
    Sub ToggleAspectRatio()

With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange

MsgBox .LockAspectRatio

'On Error GoTo err_handler:
  'Unlock
    If .LockAspectRatio = msoCTrue Then .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
  'Lock
    If .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse Then .LockAspectRatio = msoCTrue

End With
On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub

'Error Handler - No Object is Currently Selected
 
 err_handler:
  MsgBox "No object is selected"
  Exit Sub
    
End Sub
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first **If** statement sets LockAspectRatio to false, your second detects the false and sets it back to true. Instead, use an **Else** statement:

```
If .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue Then
    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
Else
    .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
End If
```

Comment: Or a one liner `.LockAspectRatio = Not .LockAspectRatio`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  A few too many errors on my behalf.

Here's the working code:

```
Sub ToggleAspectRatio()

'PURPOSE: Toggle Lock Aspect Ratio Property on/off
 
Dim ShapeName As String

On Error GoTo err_handler
    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    
    If .LockAspectRatio = True Then
        .LockAspectRatio = False
    Else
        .LockAspectRatio = True
    End If
    End With
Exit Sub
   
err_handler:
  MsgBox "No object is selected"
  Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Thanks @johnk

Comment: You should mark John's answer correct, as he told you what the problem and solution is and it will give you a few points rep.